# Apache 2.4.6 httpd binaries for Solaris 10

Tags: apache

Does anyone know where I can find precompiled binaries for Apache 2.4.6 on a 64bit Solaris 10 sparc box? I am not root on the system so it needs to be self contained in a directory I can control.

I have successfully compiled a version myself following the steps in the Apache documentation however the number of dependencies (APR, PCRE, APR-UTILS etc.) are making me second guess whether I have created a proper vanilla installation.

Comment: Does it work? Then you have! Do you need SSL support? That was historically the tricky part. If you are worried about security you should modify or create your httpd.conf so that only the modules you need are enabled.

Comment: Yes it does work. I have bundled the PCRE into the install as well. Thank you for your reply. Now I can focus on the .conf files from here on in. SSL seems to be working using Solaris' OpenSSL libraries.